# Fixing polygon with incorrectly defined hole in R

Tags: r, geometry, sp, donut-polygons, holes

[image]

I've been given this polygon as a `SpatialPolygons` object from the `sp` package.

It looks like there is a problem with how this was created, there is an unwanted line connecting the hole to the outer boundary.  How can I remove this line?  I'd like to do this within R, I don't have any other GIS software installed on this machine.  I only have this object, I don't have this information in any other format.

Here is a summary of the polygon object:

```r
> str(bnd)                                                                                           
Formal class 'SpatialPolygons' [package "sp"] with 4 slots                                           
  ..@ polygons   :List of 1                                                                          
  .. ..$ :Formal class 'Polygons' [package "sp"] with 5 slots                                        
  .. .. .. ..@ Polygons :List of 1                                                                   
  .. .. .. .. ..$ :Formal class 'Polygon' [package "sp"] with 5 slots                                
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ labpt  : num [1:2] 324832 6242992                                            
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ area   : num 2.26e+09                                                        
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ hole   : logi FALSE                                                          
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ ringDir: int 1                                                               
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ coords : num [1:1495, 1:2] 305672 306611 307040 307702 307709 ...            
  .. .. .. ..@ plotOrder: int 1                                                                      
  .. .. .. ..@ labpt    : num [1:2] 324832 6242992                                                   
  .. .. .. ..@ ID       : chr "1"                                                                    
  .. .. .. ..@ area     : num 2.26e+09                                                               
  ..@ plotOrder  : int 1                                                                             
  ..@ bbox       : num [1:2, 1:2] 299008 6194218 358295 6294754                                      
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2                                                               
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "x" "y"                                                                      
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "min" "max"                                                                  
  ..@ proj4string:Formal class 'CRS' [package "sp"] with 1 slot                                      
  .. .. ..@ projargs: chr NA
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object is stored as a single ring, so there's no indication of where the break is.

You will have to take that `@coords` matrix, figure out which are the outer coordinates and which are the hole, then reassemble the parts into two rings.

If you can install QGIS (free, open source GIS) then there's graphical ways to select vertices of polygons and create new features.

I'd suggest in R you carefully draw a polygon that divides the hole from the rest, then get the points and split them according to intersection with that new polygon.

`bnd@Polygons[[1]]@coords` should get you an Nx2 coordinate matrix of the feature vertices.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I'd rather not install QGIS on this machine, I think it will be quite fiddly (I'm on ubuntu 20.04 and last time I tried I just hit loads of errors installing dependencies and I gave up).

I like the idea of drawing another polygon, do you know of any nice way to do this within R?

Comment: Look at `locator` for drawing things on a plot device.

Comment: This worked a treat in the end, wasn't too painful. I used `gglocator` from the `ggmap` package in the end.  Then given two matrices of coordinates I used `Polygon(...,hole = TRUE)` for the hole when creating the `sp` object again.